# Codeigniter Application showing 404 not found

Tags: php, apache, codeigniter

I've deployed my codeigniter application to ssl server. This application is working in my pc but creating problem in client server. Homepage loads ok but when try to browse other links then showing The requested URL /index.php/register was not found on this server.
Apache/2.2.22 Server at mydomain.com Port 443

Looking help from experts. I've check all link and url all of them are ok.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)    
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

```
# Without mod_rewrite, route 404's to the front controller
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
```

actually problem occured when I'm putting / after index.php

Comment: what is with your .htaccess file? did you update it after uploading to server?

Comment: Your site not configured properly for running on server.Check if your .htaccess is updated as per your domain also check what is your base_url ?

Comment: I tried using base_url empty and by setting mydomain.com but no luck. One more things default controller loader without any problem but causing problem when I'm going browse other controller function.

Comment: https://mydomain.com/index.php this links works but https://mydomain.com/index.php/ not working showing 404 not found this problems occurred when I'm going to use / after index.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok finally I got the solution

htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [PT,L]
RewriteRule !^[A-Za-z0-9_/\-\.]*$ - [L,R=404]
```

and set $config['base_url']='yoursitename.com'
and set $config['index_page]=''